# Express 404 Not Found Error on PUT endpoint

Tags: node.js, express

I get 404 Not Found Error when I call "publish-template" endpoint after clicked Submit button. Why does this error occur if it really exists?

Pug render the view with correct /path for form action:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    title Translations
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/style.css")
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/translations.css")
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100,200,300,400")
  body
    form(id="msform" role="form" action="/publish-template" method="PUT")
      fieldset
        h2.fs-title Translations 
        h3.fs-subtitle Manage translations with Firebase Remote Config.
        div.grid-container
          div.grid-item
            label(for="uploads") Upload file (JSON)
            input(type="file", name="publish", id="uploads", accept=".json" multiple)
        input.submit(type="submit", name="submit", placeholder="Submit")
```

Not having a good code organization... Among other configurations, the /publish-template endpoint, using multer middleware:

```
import admin from "firebase-admin";
import express, { urlencoded } from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import path from "path";
import { request as _request } from "https";
import * as fs from "fs";
import multer from "multer";
import serviceAccount from "./placeholders/service-account.json" assert { type: "json" };
import { getDirname } from "./utils.js";

const __dirname = getDirname(import.meta.url);

const upload = multer({ dest: "uploads/" });

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});

app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "pug");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With");
  // allow preflight
  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    res.send(200);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.render("index"));
app.get("/translations", (req, res) => res.render("translations"));

// ...

function validateTemplate(template) {
  return admin
    .remoteConfig()
    .validateTemplate(template)
    .then(function (validatedTemplate) {
      return true;
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.error("Template is invalid and cannot be published", err);
      return false;
    });
}

app.put(
  "/publish-template",
  upload.single("publish"),
  async (req, res, next) => {
    const config = admin.remoteConfig();
    let template;

    try {
      if (!req.file) {
        throw new Error("No file uploaded");
      }

      const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path, "UTF8");
      template = config.createTemplateFromJSON(fileContent);

      const isValid = await validateTemplate(template);
      if (!isValid) {
        return nex(new Error("Template is invalid"));
      }
    } catch (err) {
      return next(new Error(err));
    }

    config
      .publishTemplate(template)
      .then((updatedTemplate) => {
        console.log("Template has been published");
        console.log("ETag from server: " + updatedTemplate.etag);
        res.status(200).send("Template has been published");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error("Failed to publish template: ", err);
      next(err);
    });
  },
);
```

Comment: Since you are trying to send files, shouldn't the form have a property `enctype="multipart/form-data"` ?

Comment: I have to check this for next time. @Quentin [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4526286/15551913) to that old post it's a good point to remember.

Answer (score 0):

Following [Form submission](https://www.w3.org/html/wg/spec/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#attr-fs-enctype) Draft to answer mine question:

```
form(id="msform" role="form" action="/publish-template" method="PUT", enctype="multipart/form-data")
```

---

**UPDATE**

The "publish-template" endpoint is defined as a PUT request. In my HTML (Pug) form, the method is also set as PUT. HTML forms only support GET and POST method, [developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data).